# why it output: the query is empty

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
if (isset($_GET['projectID']))
{

    $query = "SELECT taskID, name, startDate, endDate
              FROM Task
              WHERE projectID =" . $_GET['projectID'] . "
              ORDER BY taskID ASC";
} 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die( "Unable to execute query:".mysql_error());
echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='q7.php?projectID=" . $_GET['projectID'] . '&taskID=' . $row['taskID'] . "'>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['startDate']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['endDate']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

i am trying to output the information of the projectID, which is got from another php. But the output is :the query is empty.
What's wrong with the code? 
I have omit the codes that not matter.
please give me some advice.

The projectID isn't passed in correctly. And the following is the passing in code. Could you please help me figure out the bug?

```
echo "<form method='GET' action='q6.php'>";
echo "ProjectIDs and names:";
echo "<select>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['projectID']."' width='150'>";
    echo $row['projectID'].": ".$row['name'];
    echo "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";


echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`.

Comment: Try to echoing the query and run it in mysql console.

Comment: You should wrap everything in your first `if` statement as the code does not make sense outside of it.

Comment: you say you want `productID` but you are using `projectID`.

Comment: Just echo `$_GET['projectID']` to see if it is even populated. Sounds like it's not being passed in correctly.

Comment: It's not passed in correctly. And the following is the passing in code.Could you please help me have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include your query execute right after you set the query string:

```
echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html>";

if (isset($_GET['projectID']))
{
    mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query = "SELECT taskID, name, startDate, endDate
              FROM Task
              WHERE projectID =" . $_GET['projectID'] . "
              ORDER BY taskID ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die( "Unable to execute query:".mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo "<a href='q7.php?projectID=" . $_GET['projectID'] . '&taskID=' . $row['taskID'] . "'>";
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['startDate']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['endDate']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo '$_GET[\'projectID\'] is not set!';
    echo '$_GET = ';
    var_dump($_GET);

}
```

so when you generate your form you should set a name for your select:

```
echo '<select name = "projectID">';
```

Comment: I have tried it '$_GET[\'projectID\'] is not set!'; So the projectID has not been passed in correctly.

Comment: so what url do you call to get this page in browser?

Comment: It's the cs department's local host

Comment: @user2999284 check update at the bottom of my answer